# All folders open in new windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, regsvr32

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate - 32 bit. Out of nowhere, this morning when I started my PC, every single folder that I double-clicked opened a new window. That's quite annoying. Even though the options in the Folder Settings is set to "Open each folder in same window". Only when I right click and click "Open", the folder opens in the same window.

I read an article on that exact problem [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/14562-open-each-folder-same-own-separate-new-window.html)

I tried `regsvr32 "%SystemRoot%\System32\actxprxy.dll"` which works ok and `regsvr32 "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"` which gives me the  following  error:
[image: the error]

**Exact Translation:**

> Failed to load module " C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll".
>
> Make sure the binary data stored in the specified path or debug it to check for the presence of any problems with bilateral  DLL files or affiliates.
>
> Could not access the specified module.

Anyways, I restarted but still the same. All folders open in new windows.

Also, Iv'e read that this problem is connected with Internet Explorer, I am currently looking into that.

Comment: Please check addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check default value of the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell` registry key. File explorer would behave as described in case `opennewwindow`:

```
==> reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell" /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
    (Default)    REG_SZ    opennewwindow
```

The value should be either *empty*:

```
==> reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell" /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
    (Default)    REG_SZ
```

or *undefined*:

```
==> reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell" /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
```

**Addendum**. Another cause under `HKCR\Folder\shell\open` key: if `LaunchExplorerFlags` value *exists* and its data is not equal to `0x0` then its non-zero value **overrides** the *Open each folder in same window* setting, for instance ([poorly documented](https://windowssucks.wordpress.com/file-type-registration/), see also its another use in [Disable Open Folder In New Window, In Windows 8 Explorer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-open-folder-window-windows-8-explorer)):

- `0x1` is equivalent to `HKCR\Folder\shell\opennewwindow`;
- `0x3` is equivalent to `HKCR\Folder\shell\opennewprocess`;
- `0x18` could comport with `HKCR\Folder\shell\explore` (however not tested under `open` key).

The `LaunchExplorerFlags` value should either be missing as follows

```
==> reg query "HKCR\Folder\shell\open" /v LaunchExplorerFlags

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value
```

or show

```
==> reg query "HKCR\Folder\shell\open" /v LaunchExplorerFlags

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open
    LaunchExplorerFlags    REG_DWORD    0x0
```

**Example**

```
==> reg query "HKCR\Folder\shell\open" /s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open
    MultiSelectModel    REG_SZ    Document
    LaunchExplorerFlags    REG_DWORD    0x0

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe
    DelegateExecute    REG_SZ    {11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}
```

Comment: Weird thing is , it is undefined when i checked now

Comment: Thanks sir , but the issue was related to faulty internet explorer , thanks anyway