# Windows Explorer will open each new folder in New Window (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-explorer

OS: Windows 11 2H22621.126522.

Issue: Even though Windows Explorer Option is set to: Open folder in the same window, each double click opens a new explorer window.

I have tried a few remedies including looking for this Registry entries from this prior post for a different version of Windows.

Comment: My issue is that when I click on any folder in an explorer window, it spawns a new window. No tabs. So, if I want to get to a folder 5 layers in, I have a clutter of windows.

See an older version with same issue here with registry tweaks. I dont see the entry in this post. https://superuser.com/questions/993060/all-folders-open-in-new-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is the designed behavior.

Windows Explorer now has a tabbed interface,and clicking a new instance of Windows Explorer opens a new Window (even though the Option says Same Window.

I checked this on 3 Windows 11 Pro V22H2 machines and that is how it works.

This keeps tabs in one Window separate from tabs in another window.

So this is the correct behavior as designed at this point.

**Follow up**:

In V22H2, Window Instances do not combine, and tabs cannot be removed from a Window.

This may change but that is the situation now.

Comment: Windows and tabs like Firefox? Interesting! But yes they should rename this option. But what when Window crashes? I guess all its tab crash? Is there an option or by default to have a process per tab? - didn't test W11 here...

Comment: Windows 11 Tabs in Explorer is a brand new built in interface.  I saw this in Insider a while back. There is no "process per tab" that I can see here.

Comment: @Sylvain - I have never seen File Explorer crash unless it was caused by third-party software, even then, it’s only File Explorer.

Comment: Windows Explorer does not crash on my computers/ Each window has multiple tabs.

Comment: It still could have been interesting to see how many explorer.exe are in the Task Manager when you've 2+ windows and/or 2+ tabs. Maybe it's just me? Anyway, I'll check this later on.

Comment: I do not see "explorer" or "file explorer" processes in Task Manager. They may be burried. But information I saw in Insider said that File Explorer was specially programmed to accommodate tabs.

Comment: There is one process per window, as I see on my machine.
Also, I dont think John's answer is quite on target for my question.
I have no tabs, all new windows for every doubleclick

Comment: Open File Explorer only once. There is  tab labeled Home. Beside that is a plus sign . Click on +  and a new tab opens. So there are tabs

Comment: Sure. MY question was unrelated to tabs John.
My issue is my explorer keeps opening new windows, instead of the same window opening the folder, I want to open.

Comment: Windows 11 22H2 File Explorer opens each new instance in a new Window, not the same Window. My answer does say this.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood. So, your answer was related to the opening of folders by doubleclicking on them, not launching new explorer windows. Thanks for the answer!